# remove box borders

Tags: graphics, boxes, minipage

I have the following code, in which I fit three logos into a box:

```
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
  \setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}{14em}
            \includegraphics[height=4em]{images/logo1.png} \\
            \includegraphics[height=4em]{images/logo2.png} 
            \includegraphics[height=4em]{images/logo3.jpg}
        \end{minipage}
    }
  }
```

Now, I don't want the borders/margins of this box to appear. Is there an option somewhere to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a FrameBOX instead you can use an `\mbox`. See this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-boxes-in-latex

Comment: Just drop the use of `\fbox`, or set `\fboxrule` to `0pt` (not `0.5pt`).

Comment: Setting it to 0pt worked, thank you!

Comment: why use fbox with 0pt rules? that just causes TeX to do a lot of work for no visible effect? just use \mbox instead as in the first comment. (Note that your box has a word space either side of the minipage, which you may want to omit by putting % as in `\mbox{%`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should simply write

```
\begin{minipage}{14em}
  \includegraphics[height=4em]{images/logo1.png} \\
  \includegraphics[height=4em]{images/logo2.png}
  \includegraphics[height=4em]{images/logo3.jpg}
\end{minipage}
```

There is no need to enclose the `minipage` into an `\fbox` (which by default draws the borders) nor to set parameters. A `minipage` environment by itself forms a box (without drawing the borders).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example which illustrates one way to achieve this effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{14em}
    \rule{14em}{0.4pt}\rule{0.4pt}{4em} \\
    \rule{14em}{0.4pt}\rule{0.4pt}{4em}
    \rule{14em}{0.4pt}\rule{0.4pt}{4em}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```