# Vertical whitespace inside tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz node that looks like this:

[image]

It was generated using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center]{%
Tableau 0\\
\smallskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}TEXT\\TEXT\end{tabular}
};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see that the `\smallskip` was ignored. I suspect the problem was that TeX was not in the right mode -- vertical mode?

I thought I would get around the problem by wrapping the 'Tableau 0' and `\\smallskip` in a vertical-mode box.  But unfortunately, it looks like all of those boxes require you to specify their width (cf. [What are the different kinds of boxes in (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-boxes-in-latex) ), and I would need something that stretches to the width of its content.

What's the easiest way to insert the whitespace here?

Comment: Do you need a table header inside the node? Two nodes or a matrix node would avoid this naturally.

Comment: I've been experimenting and two nodes worked well once I found out about 'north'.

Comment: Why do you want insert a `\smallkip` there anyway? Do you want to fix the tight spacing between `Tableau 0` and the first line in the `tabular` environment? Then I’d suggest you try `Tableau 0\\\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}TEXT\\TEXT\end{tabular}` (notice the `[t]`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I wanted less than a full line of whitespace.

Comment: @Mohan I’m just saying. The output of `\\\\[\smallskipamount]` and `\\\begin{tabular}[t]` seem very similar. I would even combine both methods if you want an _additional_ (more than the normal baseline skip) between the caption and the first line of the `tabular`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Tableau 0\\ \smallskip`, use `Tableau 0\\[1cm]`, or whatever distance you want.

Comment: Well, I’d suggest  `\\[\smallskipamount]` to get the same skip that `\smallskip` produces (or `\\\\[\smallskipamount` to get that of `\\\smallskip`).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I didn't know that. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of are:

1. Use a `\parbox`
2. Use the `varwidth` environment.

[image]

### Notes:

- `\parbox` does require a specification of the width so may not be preferable.
- Even though `varwidth` requires you to specify the width, that specification is the maximum width. The actual width is just the natural width of the content.  So that is why in the MWE it is specified as `\linewidth`, some amount that you know is sufficiently large.
- A `\bigskip` was used in the MWE to make the spacing more obvious.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center]{\parbox{2cm}{%
Tableau 0\\
\par\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}TEXT\\TEXT\end{tabular}
}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center]{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
Tableau 0\\
\par\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}TEXT\\TEXT\end{tabular}
\end{varwidth}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```