# Adjust placement of commas and periods in TikZ txt style

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the example below, one can see that a comma and a period following a word on the baseline in a TikZ environment is based on how far the node above the word stretches towards the right. How can I change this so that the comma and the period don't care about the node above the word, but only by the word itself?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\Aheight}
\setlength{\Aheight}{\fontcharht\font`A}

\newcommand{\phraselabel}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline = (word.base),
        txt/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text height = \Aheight, draw},
        above/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text depth = 0pt, draw}%
        ]
    \node[txt] (word) {#1};
    \node[above] at (word.north) {\footnotesize{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
\phraselabel{bb}{xxxxx}, \phraselabel{bb}{xxxxx}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the comma just after the `bb`?

Comment: @Sigur Right - I'd like the placement of the comma and the period to be exactly as it would be if the nodes above weren't there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example lets `\phraselabel` look ahead, whether a comma or period is following. If the punctuation char is found, it is read as argument and put behind the word.

The first line of the example uses the boxed version, but the punctuation char is left outside, because it does not belong to the word. For the case, the punctuation char should be inside the box or the boxes are just for debugging, the second line shows the simplified version without boxes.

Another feature is implemented, the handling of the space factor. In order to add a larger space after full stops with `\nonfrenchspacing`, TeX keeps track of a space factor. The example saves the space factor after the word inside the node and restores it after the `tikzpicture`. See the larger space between "cc." and "New".

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\Aheight}
\setlength{\Aheight}{\fontcharht\font`A}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\phraselabel}[2]{%
    \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace,{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%
    \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace.{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%
    \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace;{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%
    \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace!{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%
    \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace?{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%
        \@phraselabel{#1}{#2}{}%
    }}}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@phraselabel}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline = (word.base),
        txt/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text height = \Aheight, draw},
        above/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text depth = 0pt, draw}%
        ]
    \node[txt] (word) {#1\phrase@save@spacefactor};
    \ifx\\#3\\
    \else
      \node[anchor=base, right, inner sep=0pt]
        at (word.base east)
        {\phrase@set@spacefactor#3\phrase@save@spacefactor};
    \fi
    \node[above] at (word.north) {\footnotesize{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \phrase@set@spacefactor
}
\newcount\phrase@spacefactor
\newcommand*{\phrase@save@spacefactor}{%
    \global\phrase@spacefactor=\spacefactor
}
\newcommand*{\phrase@set@spacefactor}{%
    \spacefactor=\phrase@spacefactor
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% With boxes
\phraselabel{aa}{xxxxx}
\phraselabel{bb}{yyyyy},
\phraselabel{cc}{zzzzz}.
\phraselabel{New}{xxxxx}
\phraselabel{sentence}{yyyyy}.

% Without boxes
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@phraselabel}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline = (word.base),
        txt/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text height = \Aheight},
        above/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text depth = 0pt}%
        ]
    \node[txt] (word) {#1#3\phrase@save@spacefactor};
    \node[above] at (word.north) {\footnotesize{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \phrase@set@spacefactor
}
\makeatother
\phraselabel{aa}{xxxxx}
\phraselabel{bb}{yyyyy},
\phraselabel{cc}{zzzzz}.
\phraselabel{New}{xxxxx}
\phraselabel{sentence}{yyyyy}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` of package `ltxcmds` is used for the look ahead. In contrary to LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar`, it does not gobble spaces, when looking ahead.

Comment: I'd like to also do this when the following character is ``!`` or ``?``. I tried to simply add ``\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace!{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%`` and ``\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace?{\@phraselabel{#1}{#2}}{%`` below your other ``\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace`` commands, but I get an error ``Runaway argument? {\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace ,{\@phraselabel {##1}{##2}}{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace \E TC.`` Could you please include commands for ``!`` and ``?`` in your code?

Comment: @Sverre Probably only some closing curly braces were missing. I have now added support for `;`, `!`, and `?`.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack to remember you could just use \hphantom{}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\Aheight}
\setlength{\Aheight}{\fontcharht\font`A}

\newcommand{\phraselabel}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline = (word.base),
        txt/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text height = \Aheight, draw},
        above/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text depth = 0pt, draw}%
        ]
    \node[txt] (word) {#1};
    \node[above] at (word.north) {\footnotesize{#2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
\phraselabel{\hphantom{,}bb,}{xxxxx} \phraselabel{\hphantom{.}bb.}{xxxxx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have, but the problem then is that the node above will no longer be centered with respect to ``bb``, but to ``bb`` + comma/period.

Comment: I have updated my problem with a solution using \hphantom{} to balance the left and the right side. \hphantom{} and \vphantom{} can often be used for stuff like this for quick fixes. (Edit) I just thought I would also mention if you don't like seeing \hphantom{} in \phraselabel{} you can write a macro to auto balance it on either side with something like \newcommand{\bal}[2]{\hphantom{#1} #2 #1}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\rlap{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\Aheight}
\setlength{\Aheight}{\fontcharht\font`A}

\newcommand{\phraselabel}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline = (word.base),%
        txt/.style = {inner sep = 0pt, text height = \Aheight},%
        tag/.style = {above=0.75ex, inner sep = 0pt, text depth = 0pt}%
        ]%
    \node[txt] (word) {#1};%
    \node[tag] at (word.north) {\footnotesize{#2}};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
\phraselabel{gg}{xxxxx} \phraselabel{aa}{jjjjj} \phraselabel{tt}{xxxxx} \phraselabel{bb\rlap{.}}{xxxxx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Relevant links for people wanting to know what ``\rlap`` does are [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98800/9077) and [here](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#makebox).

Comment: Sorry, yes, I had to run before explaining how it works.