# How to put \algorithm and \algorithmic environments inside a box?

Tags: boxes, algorithmic

I want to put an algorithm inside a box. Here is the code

```
\fbox{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \scriptsize
...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

}}
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Not in outer par mode
```

following other error at the line where the two ending curly brackets are. The problem is solved when i remove the `algorithm` environment and i have only the `algorithmic`. But i want to have algorithm environment to put the caption.

Comment: Have a look at the `algorithm2e`, or the `listings` package. With the old `algorithm` stuff this is not easily possible.

Comment: `algorithm` is a float environment. If you put the box only in `algorithmic` it should work. `\begin{algorithm}\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth} \begin{algorithmic} ... \end{agorithmic} \end{minipage}} end{algorithm}`

Comment: Is there any need for using `\fbox` and `\parbox` instead of `algorithm2e` box features ? see more [primitive TeX boxes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83930/15717)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make that a real answer: If you want a box around

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \scriptsize
  \STATE Statement
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: original output]

I suggest to switch to the `algorithm2e` package. The above can be roughly mimicked with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
% \RestyleAlgo{boxed}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\LinesNumbered
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{My algorithm\label{alg}}
  Statement
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: boxed output]

Comment: Yes but the first approach is not surrounded by a box

Comment: No it's not. In my original i have the fbox and pbox commands.

Comment: @curious Yeah I removed the nonworking part to show something.

Comment: If you remove it this is not an answer to my question.As it is not why i want to do.

Comment: @curious Now you even downvoted me? What the hell ... I just showed how a *working* example of `algorithmic` would look like, and then how a boxed version using `algorithm2e` looks like.

Comment: @mafp Hi there. I am trying to adopt your suggestion with the ```boxruled``` enabled on a double column page document. It works but after the line numbers exceed 10 then they get outside of the box. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can not have any kind of float in a box, you would get the same from `figure` or `table`,
The most direct solution is not to use a float and use the (one line) `capt-of` package to allow use of a caption

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
```

then

```
\fbox{\parbox{0.8\linewidth}{
%\begin{algorithm}
\captionof{algorithm}{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \scriptsize
...
\end{algorithmic}
%\end{algorithm}

}}
```

However it is probably better to use an algorithm package that allows a boxed float style (or use the `float` package to style such floats) then the box is inside the float so the construct may still be floated by LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is yet another quite recent algorithm-like package called [algpseudocodex](https://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocodex), which indeed allows for drawing boxes around pieces of code. I guess the LaTeX code you are looking for is as simple as

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \scriptsize
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \BeginBox
        \State first line
        \State ...
    \EndBox
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

after specifying `\usepackage{algpseudocodex}` in the file header.