# Subfigure with lstlisting: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: floats, listings, subfloats

It keeps telling me: `\begin{document} ended by \end{figure}`, but I do not understand why. I tried to follow the guidelines for [the subfigure package](http://ftp.twaren.net/Unix/TeX/CTAN/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf). Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
nothing in it
\end{subfigure}
\qquad
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{lstlisting}
The code
With a line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A program and its corresponding trace.\label{figuretrace}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I also tried the command `\subfigure` without success. I just would like to be able to embed a lstlisting environment inside a subfigure.

What is wrong?

**EDIT**

Another environment, algorithm, does not work either:

```
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{algorithm}
The code
With a line
\end{algorithm}
\end{subfigure}
```

Nor does this work with a table, tabular... Why not?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\lstlisting` is a verbatim environment. In that case, it can't be stuffed inside another environment. Perhaps the `verbatimbox` package would give an acceptable alternative to `lstlisting` for your situation.

Comment: David Carlisle may have a solution to the algorithm problem at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110206/how-to-put-algorithm-and-algorithmic-environments-inside-a-box.  Once you save it in a box, you can regurgitate the box in the subfigure.

Comment: Please read the [IEEEtran-HOWTO](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf). The usage of `subfigure` is not recommended; you should use `subfig` instead (pags 9 and 10 of the HOWTO). Also the `algorithm` floating environment shouldn't be used with this class (page 10 of the HOWTO document).

Comment: subfig yields the same errors in my case. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

using my `verbatimbox` suggestion from the comment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
The code
With a line
\end{verbbox}
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{subfigure}
nothing in it
\end{subfigure}
\qquad
\begin{subfigure}
\theverbbox
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A program and its corresponding trace.\label{figuretrace}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution. I need a refinement (see my question)

Comment: @MikaëlMayer  In my toolbox, I have a hammer with `verbatimbox` written on it, but I can't find my `algorithm` hammer at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the recommendation from the [`IEEEtran-HOWTO document`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)

1. The use of the obsolete `subfigure` package is not recommended; you should use `subfig` instead (pags 9 and 10).
2. The `algorithm` floating environment from the `algorithm` or `algorihtm2e` packages shouldn't be used with this class (page 10).

In the following example I used the `subfig` package (loaded as recommended in the HOWTO document) to include the subfigures; the listing was saved in a `lrbox` first, and then the box was used inside the `\subfloat` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}
The code
With a line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{%
nothing in it
}\qquad
\subfloat{\usebox\mybox}\qquad
\caption{A program and its corresponding trace.\label{figuretrace}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]