# Use algorithm2e inside tcolorbox

Tags: algorithm2e, tcolorbox

I use the [`algorithm2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) package to typeset algorithms. Now I would like to put a `tcolorbox` around an algorithm. My first approach looked like this:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{algorithm}
        $a \leftarrow 1$
        \caption{My Algorithm}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

This yields the following error: `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` My understanding is that this happens because both the `tcolorbox` and the `algorithm` are floating environments that cannot be nested.

There is already a similar question: [How to put \algorithm and \algorithmic environments inside a box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110206/how-to-put-algorithm-and-algorithmic-environments-inside-a-box) The accepted answer there does not work for me, because it simply describes how to put an arbitrary box around the algorithm. I also tried to use `\RestyleAlgo{tcolorbox}`, but to no avail. I am looking for a method that specifically uses a `tcolorbox`.

As a final remark, I do not need to typeset the algorithms particularly with `algorithm2e`, any other algorithm package will do as well.

Comment: To complement both answers: a `tcolorbox` is not floating by default, but you can add the `float` option key to make it floating. Second, an alternative to the caption could be using a `title` for the `tcolorbox` (depends what the result should look like).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error "Not in outer par mode" is because the `algorithm` environment wants to float, yet it's contained inside a non-floating `tcolorbox`. The only way to make [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) not floats its algorithms is to use the `[H]` float specifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper size={15cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    $a \leftarrow 1$
    \caption{My Algorithm}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative. The [LaTeX Wikibook section on algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithmicx_package) has the following statement.

The `algorithmicx` package provides a number of popular constructs for algorithm designs. Put `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` in the preamble to use the algorithmic environment to write algorithm pseudocode (`\begin{algorithmic}...\end{algorithmic}`). You might want to use the algorithm environment (`\usepackage{algorithm}`) to wrap your algorithmic code in an algorithm environment (`\begin{algorithm}...\end{algorithm}`) to produce a floating environment with numbered algorithms.

With that said, without `algorithm` environment means non-floating. Thus, it can be put inside `tcolorbox` environment, consequently, `caption` package is required for the `\caption` for the algorithm. Remember to add the package `algpseudocode` statement to your document preamble.

[image]

The following is an example of code that yields the result shown above.

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper size={15cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{mytype}[Algorithm][List of MyType]
\newenvironment{myenv}{}{}

\begin{document}
\listofmytypes

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \centering
\begin{algorithmic}
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets 0$
\Else
    \If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets i+k$
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\captionof{mytype}{My Algorithm}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```