# Math mode inside LyX tables

Tags: tables, lyx, vertical-alignment

If I insert a math mode environment inside a table cell, then the output will show no vertical space between the borders and the equation, here is an example:

> [image]

Is there any way that will make the borders have more vertical space from the formula?

Comment: If you insert a simple `float table`, you can see the `settings` menu via: R-click on table -> Other... -> Settings -> Borders. Here you can add or subtract vertical space below, above the row. The best typographical advice is to switch the `formal` border setting, this will *automatically* set both the looking and the spacing of the entire table.

Comment: @Andrea L. Shouldn't this be posted as an `answer`?

Comment: @landroni For the sake of coherence, yes. The moment I'll be able to typeset it nicely it will be posted (this delay is due to my first year as a freshmen, so I didn't have too much time)...`;)`

Comment: @AndreaL. I sew your answer now... Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman Firstly, you're welcome; and secondly, due to my first university exams, I'll post your deserved decent answer in two-three weeks (I'm sorry, I know this is uncoherent, but right now I don't have the basic material: time)

Comment: @AndreaL., How I can insert a float table? Thank you!

Comment: @YoavFridman Inside the top menu bar there is a button called `insert`, if you click on it there will be a window showing all the fields you can insert like math, figures and `floating objects`; selecting that allows you to choose from `figure, table`. Once selected `table`, you'll have a floating space containing a table.

Comment: @AndreaL., I tried, but I didn't get the space at the cells...

Comment: @AndreaL., I try do to as you said but I didn't get the spaces :-(

Comment: @YoavFridman This seems strange, I tried on my machine and worked. Could you please show your result with my suggested method (formal table)?

Comment: @AndreaL. can you show my how you define the spaces please? (PrintScreen of the settings menu).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12562/discussion-between-andrea-l-and-yoav-fridman)

Comment: @AndreaL. where is the chat?

Comment: Just click the annotation `let us continue this discussion in chat`, I'll meet you there `:)`.

Comment: @AndreaL. Would you have time to write an answer now?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'd like to, and I'm terribly sorry for my delay (holy smoke, almost four months of waiting!); I think Yoav Fridman deserves more than a coffee for the patience.

Comment: @AndreaL. Take your time!! :-).

Comment: After a fight to the death with five `\expandafter`, the answer is coming out today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather simple workaround can be constructed using plain TeX/LaTeX `boxes` handling; since LaTeX's cell vertical space takes no account for the command `\displaystyle`, one solution is to avoid it "a priori" by inserting the equation inside a [`parbox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-boxes-in-latex) environment:

```
\parbox[⟨alignment⟩][⟨height⟩][⟨arrangement⟩]{⟨width⟩}{⟨contents⟩}
```

Firstly, the `alignment` and `arrangement` parameters are set centered (`c`); the interesting dimensional arguments are `height` and `width`: since the equation will have stored its specific height (above the baseline), depth (below the baseline) and width, these dimensions could be easily substituted inside parbox's optional/mandatory arguments using [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc)'s commands:

```
total height: \totalheightof{⟨content⟩}+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule  (pt)
total width : \widthof{⟨content⟩}                             (pt)
```

noticing that this setting can be applied to *both* any text or math inside the box, a useful macro `\mytabspace{⟨your equation⟩}` could be created, defined by:

```
% implementing more dimension/expression handling control sequences
\usepackage{calc}
%
\newcommand\mytabspace[1]{%
 \parbox[c][\totalheightof{#1}+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][c]{\widthof{#1}}{#1}%
}
```

Another equivalent solution would be storing the content of the sub-cell inside a temporary box `\@tempboxa`; therefore there would be no worries about repetitive implementation inside the document, because if the box dimensions are defined inside a group, once outside the command they reset to the new box contents:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytabspace[1]{% 
 \sbox\@tempboxa{#1}%
 \parbox[c][\ht\@tempboxa+\dp\@tempboxa+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][c]{\wd\@tempboxa}{%
  \usebox\@tempboxa%
 }%
}
\makeatother
```

Seeing it in action with a simple MWE paids off all the work behind:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{calc}
%
\newcommand\mytabspace[1]{%
 \parbox[c][\totalheightof{#1}+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][c]{\widthof{#1}}{#1}%
}
% comment out the lines below and comment the beforementioned command,
% you'll see that the output is the same.
%\makeatletter
%\newcommand\mytabspace[1]{% 
% \sbox\@tempboxa{#1}%
% \parbox[c][\ht\@tempboxa+\dp\@tempboxa+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][c]{\wd\@tempboxa}{%
%  \usebox\@tempboxa%
% }%
%}
%\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Function   & Integral   \\
\hline
$-$  & This is not my macro: a   \\
\hline
% test if there are unwanted vertical space additions
$-$  & This is my macro: \mytabspace{a}  \\
\hline
% now the integral becomes:
$\sin(x)$  & \mytabspace{$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(c_k)\Delta x_k=\int_a^b\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}$}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a spaced equation, finally at last!}
\end{table}
%
\end{document}
```

With the output shown, it can be observed that `mytabspace` applies *no* modifications to any vertical spacing, as a demonstration to its versatility:

> [image]

Moving on with LyX, accessing the menu `Document ￫ Settings ￫ LaTeX preamble` any `\mytabspace` macro definition shown can be pasted; because the program itself adds automatically `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` inside the white preamble (the second code should *not* be pasted with those two commands, they'll be redundant).

At this point, the desired math environment can be delimited by a simple ERT:

> [image]

Giving the final, expected output:

> [image]

In addition, I'd like to thank @DavidCarlisle for the useful tips (but, only for the second code `=P`); and more importantly:

- [I beg you, use `booktabs`!](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/improve-your-tables-with-booktabs/)

I too encountered this issue when I was just getting started with LyX (as example, I didn't even know what did "control sequence" mean back then); but I've been able to *face it* just now.

Comment: each cell is a group and you save and use the box in the same cell so so you do not need to allocate any boxes or lengths you can use the same box (eg box0 or @tempboxa) for every cell. As a first approximation you should never use \newbox or \newlength inside anothe command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still remember your comments from yesterday's chat, and right now I'm testing the results. A new edit will come soon, probably before tonight.