# Increase vertical space in table

Tags: tables, spacing

Creating a table using `tabulary` I am confronted with the problem that the lines of my table are too small, resulting in that the formulas touch the borders of the table. The code I used is given below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabulary}{18cm}{R|L L L}
\toprule
\hline
Mean squared error & MSE &= &$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2$   \\
\hline
Root mean squared error & RMSE &= &$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2}$ \\
\hline
Mean absolute error & MAE &= &$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}|e_t|$ \\
\hline
Mean absolute percentage error & MAPE &= &$\frac{100\%}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}\left |\frac{e_t}{y_t}\right|$\\
\hline\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

How can I increase vertical space in my table so that it looks appropriate?

[image]

Comment: Even if an answer has been accepted, I suggest also to try taking a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145757/math-mode-inside-lyx-tables/164572#164572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\hline` and also remove the vertical rule that adds no information and simply interrupts the flow of reading.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabulary}{18cm}{L R @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} L}
\toprule
Mean squared error & MSE &= &$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2$   \\
\midrule
Root mean squared error & RMSE &= &$\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2}$ \\
\midrule
Mean absolute error & MAE &= &$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}|e_t|$ \\
\midrule
Mean absolute percentage error & MAPE &= &$\displaystyle\frac{100\%}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}\left |\frac{e_t}{y_t}\right|$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure you really need `tabulary`: this gives exactly the same result.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{l r @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} l}
\toprule
Mean squared error & MSE &= &$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2$   \\
\midrule
Root mean squared error & RMSE &= &$\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2}$ \\
\midrule
Mean absolute error & MAE &= &$\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}|e_t|$ \\
\midrule
Mean absolute percentage error & MAPE &= &$\displaystyle\frac{100\%}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}\left |\frac{e_t}{y_t}\right|$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I increase the width of the table, for example, so that it adopts to the width of the page?

Comment: @JohnnyB Don't do it. There's no reason (except following bad practice with word processors) for expanding a table beyond its natural width.

Answer (score 2):

Without `tabulary` (works also with `tabulary`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

{\def\arraystretch{2.5}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l r @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} l @{}}
\toprule
Mean squared error & MSE &= &$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2$   \\
\midrule
Root mean squared error & RMSE &= &$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2}$ \\
\midrule
Mean absolute error & MAE &= &$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}|e_t|$ \\
\midrule
Mean absolute percentage error & MAPE &= &$\dfrac{100\%}{n}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{n}\left |\frac{e_t}{y_t}\right|$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `cellspace` package ensures a minimal spacing between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell and independantly between the bottom of the cell and the top of the below cell. So you can have better vertical spacing of cells *and* contents of cells vertically centred, which is not the case if you play with `\arraystretch`. `Makecell` allows for horizontal lines of varying thickness, with the `Xhline` command.

In addition I simplified the original code (1 column less): \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

```
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand*{\topdblline}{\Xhline{0.15ex}\\[-2.6ex]\hline}
\newcommand*{\botdblline}{\hline\\[-2.6ex]\Xhline{0.15ex}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabulary}{18cm}{L @{\qquad}R @{${}={}$} >{$\displaystyle}SL<{$}}%{L R @{} >{${}}c<{{}$} @{} SL}
\topdblline
Mean squared error & MSE  & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2    \\
\hline
Root mean squared error & RMSE & \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}e_t^2}  \\
\hline
Mean absolute error & MAE &  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}|e_t|  \\
\hline
Mean absolute percentage error & MAPE & \frac{100\%}{n}\sum_{t=1}^{n}\left |\frac{e_t}{y_t}\right| \\
\botdblline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]