# How to specify width and height of \makebox using \widthof and \heightof without generating error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, boxes, width, height

As soon as the following (working) definition

```
\newcommand
    {\TESTFRACTION}
    {%
        \makebox
            [\widthof{${}\left(\frac{a}{1}\right){}$}]
            {${}\left(\frac{b}{1}\right){}$}
    }
```

is changed to one which also includes height

```
\newcommand
    {\TESTFRACTION}
    {%
        \makebox
            (\widthof{${}\left(\frac{a}{1}\right){}$},
             \heightof{${}\left(\frac{a}{1}\right){}$})
            {${}\left(\frac{b}{1}\right){}$}
    }
```

`! Missing number, treated as zero.` error is generated on the same line where `\TESTFRACTION` is used inside equation environment.

Following is a working version to serve as a scaffolding to try to get `\makebox' accept, both, width and height using`\widthof`and`\heightof`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand
    {\TESTFRACTION}
    {%
        \makebox
            [\widthof{${}\left(\frac{a}{1}\right){}$}]
            {${}\left(\frac{b}{1}\right){}$}
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node
            {%
                $%
                    \begin{gathered}
                        \TESTFRACTION
                    \end{gathered}
                $
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the idea or main purpose behind your macro?

Comment: Fixed-width? You're making them a width similar to what they already are. It's still not clear what your intent is... perhaps you only showed a small example that doesn't highlight the actual use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for others too, but I think, `parbox` is better to do what you want:

WE with parbox:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand
    {\TESTFRACTION}
    {%
        \parbox[c]
             [\heightof{${}\left(\frac{a}{1}\right){}$}][c]
             {\widthof{${}\left(\frac{a}{1}\right){}$}}
            {${}\left(\frac{b}{1}\right){}$}
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node
            {
                $%
                    \begin{gathered}
                        \TESTFRACTION
                    \end{gathered}
                $
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also think, that the `makebox` version you are trying to use has to be in a picture environment. And this makes things strange for your needs.

Comment: Sory... I have no time at the moment. Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83936/120578... I have to sleep now.

Answer (score 5):

Ti*k*Z has nothing to do with this: `calc` related computations are not available in coordinates, such as in `\makebox(x,y){BOX}`. By the way, the coordinates should be in multiples of `\unitlength` rather than lengths.

You can exploit `picture` for being able to pass lengths also in this case, but `\widthof` and `\heightof` are out of question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\TFW}\newlength{\TFH}

\newcommand{\TESTFRACTION}{%
  \settowidth{\TFW}{$\left(\frac{a}{1}\right)$}%
  \settoheight{\TFH}{$\left(\frac{a}{1}\right)$}%
  \makebox(\TFW,\TFH){$\left(\frac{b}{1}\right)$}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node {%
   $
   \begin{gathered}
   \TESTFRACTION
   \end{gathered}
   $%
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]