# Effectively, how to do "Underbrace" under two "Underbraces"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, horizontal-alignment, underbrace

> Goal: I am trying to find a way to write an equation for:

[image]

However, I fail, or at least so far could not find a way, to add the last layer in the bottom for "magnetic flux" using `\underbrace`.

Here is what I have so far,

```
$$
 \overbrace{ \underbrace{S^1_A \times  S^1_B}_{E} \times  \underbrace{S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}}_{\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}}
 }^{\text{ABCDEFG}} 
$$
```

and my output is this:

[image]

> Could you find a better way to do it? Effectively, how to do "Underbrace" under two "Underbraces"? Or maybe we can also try to use TikZ instead? (i.e. I don't mind to try other methods)

p.s. Another thing is that, in my case, the size of ABCDEFG is smaller than the `S^1_A \times  S^1_B  \times  S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}` — is there a way to adjust the size of ABCDEFG and others?

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\overbrace{\underbrace{S^1_A \times S^1_B}_E\times
           \underbrace{S^1_C\times\mathbb{R}}_{\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}}}^{\text{ABCDEFG}} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\underbrace{\kern5em}_{\text{magnetic flux}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is the best. I like to accept it. One more question: Suppose I put this into the figure form:

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{gather*}
......
\end{gather*}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

Comment: how do we then change/adjust the size of this figure? Can we freely zoom the size?

Comment: The size of the brace is set by the `\kern5em` and can be changed to any value you like. It is a width of 5 times the width of a capital M in the current font. Smaller font -- smaller width (automatically!)  and vice versa for greater font.

Comment: I hope to adjust the whole thing at once, not sure how to do - is it possible?

Comment: I asked a new question 467710 regarding this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1: adjust by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
 \overbrace{ \underbrace{S^1_A \times  S^1_B}_{E} 
 \makebox[7pt][c]{$\underbrace{\qquad~\times~\qquad\vphantom{\underbrace{S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}}_{\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}}}}_{\text{magnetic flux}}$}
 \underbrace{S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}}_{\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}}
 }^{\text{ABCDEFG}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Solution 2: Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\[
 \tikzmarknode{l}{S^1_A \times  S^1_B}
 \times
 \tikzmarknode{r}{S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,decoration={brace,raise=2pt},thick]
\draw[decorate] (l.north west) -- (r.north east) node[midway,above=3pt](ABC){ABCDEFG};
\draw[decorate] (l.south east) -- (l.south west) node[midway,below=3pt](E){$E$};
\draw[decorate] (r.south east) -- (r.south west) node[midway,below=3pt](CP){$\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}$};
\draw[decorate] (CP.south east) -- (E.south west|-CP.south) node[midway,below=3pt]{magnetic flux};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! I suppose I can also adjust the size of "brace" by the first or the second way?

Comment: @wonderich Yes. First way: change the `\quad`s. Second way: e.g. \draw[decorate] ([xshift=-4pt]CP.south east) -- (E.south west|-CP.south) node[midway,below=3pt]{magnetic flux};` (Will be offline now.)

Comment: @marmot: Isn't the fact that none of the braces in the second solution increase the depth of the equation potentially problematic?

Comment: @marmot, actually there is a problem, I cannot compile the 2nd option...

Comment: The error says: "undefined control sequence ... tikzmarknode"

Comment: @wonderich When was the last time you updated your TeX installation? (I am using the update `tikzmark` library, which was updated a few months ago.)

Comment: @Circumscribe Well, if you mean that you have to add the vertical space by hand, then that's true. It is true whenever you use the overlay option in a `tikzpicture`. (I had discussions on this with others, including the author of `tikzmarknode`. It is absolutely straightforward to let Ti*k*Z measure the distance the required additional distance, but AFAIK there is not yet a package that inserts it automatically.)

Comment: @marmot: You could also do it like [this](https://pastebin.com/6ySpajw1) though. (please disregard the junk at the bottom)

Comment: @Circumscribe Yes, that is a nice way. (I am never 100% sure if having `\tikzmarknode` inside a `tikzpicture` amounts to nesting `tikzpictures`. This is the reason why I did not go this path. But if you post this, I will certainly upvote it.)

Comment: @marmot: I think it does (amount to nesting Tikz pictures). My experience with TikZ is rather limited though, and I have no idea why this would be bad.

Comment: @Circumscribe In this case, you can do it because you are not setting many pgf keys. In general, please see [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/121799). In [this list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/47377?lq=1) there are several examples that illustrate what might go bad if you do that. In your case, I *believe* it is fine. But I would start with a disclaimer that this answer nests `tikzpicture`s and, if a modified version of this code is used elsewhere, you do not guarantee that everything goes smooth.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 4 (or 5): measuring boxes

I decided to create a slightly more basic version of the solution below.

The macro `\bracetree`, which I define below, creates the output you desire. 
It does does this by putting some of its arguments in box registers so that their widths can be measured.
It then uses these width to insert the right amount of space at the right places to create braces with the correct widths

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   %% <- not explicitly needed
\usepackage{amsfonts}  %% <- for \mathbb
\usepackage{mathtools} %% <- for \mathrlap, loads amsmath

\makeatletter   %% <_ make @ usable in macro names
\newcommand*\bracetree[6]{%
  \begingroup                           %% <- limit scope of assignments
    \sbox0{$\m@th\displaystyle #1$}     %% <- store arguments in box registers
    \sbox2{$\m@th #4$}
    \sbox4{$\m@th\displaystyle #3$}
    \sbox6{$\m@th #5$}
    \hspace{\dimexpr.5\wd0-.5\wd2}      %% <- insert space
    \underbrace{
      \hspace{\dimexpr-.5\wd0+.5\wd2}   %% <- remove space
        \underbrace{\copy0}_{\copy2}
          #2
        \underbrace{\copy4}_{\copy6}    %% <- remove space
      \hspace{\dimexpr-.5\wd4+.5\wd6}
    }_{\textstyle #6}
    \hspace{\dimexpr.5\wd4-.5\wd6}      %% <- insert space
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother    %% <- revert @

\begin{document}

\noindent Words before
\begin{equation}
    \overbrace{
      \bracetree{S^1_A \times  S^1_B}{\times}{S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}}
                {E}{\mathbb{CP}^{\mathrlap{N-1}}}
                {\textnormal{magnetic fluxxxx}
      }
    }^{\textstyle\textnormal{ABCDEFG}}
\end{equation}
Words after

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

#### A few notes:

- `ABCDEFG` was smaller because the text above the overbrace is effectively like a superscript, and therefore set at the corresponding font size. 
  This can be remedied by adding `\textstyle`. 
  I'm using `\textnormal` instead of `\text` because of the reasons outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98407/156366).
- I'm using positive and negative `\hspace`s that cancel out precisely to set the width of the bottom underbrace.
- I'm using `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` to negate the horizontal space taken up by `{N-1}` because I think it looks better if the superscript is ignored for the purposes of brace placement and placement relative to braces.
- `\sbox<box register>{<contents>}` stores `<contents>` in a box register. These boxes can be printed with `\copy<box register>` and their widths are given by `\wd<box register>`.
  I'm using only even box registers because these are available as [scratch  registers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83936/156366).
- `\m@th` sets `\mathsurround` (amount of horizontal space `$…$`) to zero. This is the default value, so it actually does nothing here. If you get rid of it you can also remove [`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/156366).

## Solution 3 (or 4): black magic

I made the version of `\bracetree` below earlier by sort of taking apart the definition of the original `\underbrace`. The results should mostly be the same, but it is a little harder to explain how this works (and probably for you to adapt).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   %% <- not explicitly needed
\usepackage{amsfonts}  %% <- for \mathbb
\usepackage{mathtools} %% <- for \mathrlap, loads amsmath

\makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in macro names
\newcommand\bracetree[6]{%
  \vtop{\m@th
    \sbox0{$\mathstrut\displaystyle #1$}%
    \sbox2{$\mathstrut\displaystyle #3$}%
    \sbox4{$\mathstrut #4$}%
    \sbox6{$\mathstrut #5$}%
    \ialign{##\crcr
      $\displaystyle\copy0#2\copy2$%
      \crcr
      \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      \hbox to \wd0{\upbracefill}\hfil\hbox to \wd2{\upbracefill}%
      \crcr
      \hskip.5\wd0\hskip-.5\wd4\copy4\hfil\copy6\hskip-.5\wd6\hskip.5\wd2
      \crcr
      \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      \hskip.5\wd0\hskip-.5\wd4\upbracefill\hskip-.5\wd6\hskip.5\wd2
      \crcr
      \hskip.5\wd0\hskip-.5\wd4\hidewidth\hbox{$#6$}\hidewidth\hskip-.5\wd6\hskip.5\wd2
      \crcr
      }%
  }%
}
\makeatother  %% <- revert @

\begin{document}

\noindent Words before.
\begin{equation}
    X = \overbrace{
          \bracetree{S^1_A \times S^1_B}{\times}{S^1_C \times \mathbb{R}}
                    {E}{\mathbb{CP}^{\mathrlap{N-1}}}
                    {\text{magnetic flux}}
        }^{\textstyle\text{ABCDEFG}}
\end{equation}
Words after.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I'm not really sure where to begin explaining this, but here it goes.

- `\vtop` creates a top aligned box: the first line of its contents will share a baseline with the surrounding equation. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83936/156366).
- `\ialign` is sort of like `tabular`: it allows you to align things next to each other or on top of each other.
- `\crcr` more or less does what `\\` does in a `tabular` environment
- `\noalign{\kern<length>}` inserts a little vertical space
- `\hskip<length>` inserts horizontal space
- `\hfil` and `\hidewidth` both insert a stretchable amount of space. The latter will be negative when necessary.
- `\upbracefill` fills the available space with an underbrace

## Solution 2.5: Tikz again

I've modified [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466733/156366) (with his blessing). 
The difference between this version and his version is that this increases the depth of the equation (so "Words after" is actually below "magnetic flux").

**DISCLAIMER: This nests TikZ environments!**

Nesting TikZ  environments is generally a bad idea because things like key  values and bounding boxes can leak from the inner environment to the outer one and vice versa.
While marmot believes it should be okay in this case, one should still be careful with this. 
See e.g [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/156366) and several pages linked to from there for more info.

If a modified version of this code is used elsewhere it is not guaranteed to still work smoothly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\noindent Words before
\begin{equation}
    X = \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,remember picture,decoration={brace,raise=2pt},thick]
        \node[anchor=base] {$\tikzmarknode{l}{S^1_A \times  S^1_B} \times \tikzmarknode{r}{S^1_C \times  \mathbb{R}}$};
        \draw[decorate] (l.north west) -- (r.north east) node[midway,above=3pt](ABC){ABCDEFG};
        \draw[decorate] (l.south east) -- (l.south west) node[midway,below=3pt](E){$\strut E\vphantom{^{N}}$};
        \draw[decorate] (r.south east) -- (r.south west) node[midway,below=3pt](CP){$\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}$};
        \draw[decorate] (CP.south east) -- (E.south west|-CP.south) node[midway,below=3pt]{magnetic flux};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
Words after

\end{document}
```

[image: output]