# What does \leavevmode do?

Tags: tex-core, boxes

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83930/14757) and the amazing @egreg's answer, I decided to make some tests to study and learn some boxes behavior. More precisely, to understand the `\leavevmode`.

In the first example, one horizontal box with two vertical ones inside it with some horizontal boxes there, and everything is fine.

In the second example, I put `\leavevmode` in the first vertical box and as I expected the behavior was changed to horizontal, so `aaa` and `bbb` are side-by-side.

But the output is completely affected by that. That is, the second vertical box is out or margin.

**Thus, why the second example is too wide?**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\linha}{\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[0pt]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}}

\begin{document}%
\noindent%
\hbox{%
  \vbox{%\leavevmode%
    \hbox{aaa}%
    \hbox{bbb}%
  }%
  \vtop{%
    \hbox{xxx}
    \hbox{yyy}
    \hbox{zzz}
  }%
  123456
}%

\medskip

\noindent%
\hbox{%
  \vbox{\leavevmode%
    \hbox{aaa}%
    \hbox{bbb}%
  }%
  \vtop{%
    \hbox{xxx}
    \hbox{yyy}
    \hbox{zzz}
  }%
  123456
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Function and usage of \leavevmode](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/22852)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined by

```
\newbox\voidb@x % permanently void box register
\def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x}
```

so in horizontal mode it does essentially nothing, and in vertical modes it forces the start of horizontal mode (so like the `luatex` primitive `\quitvmode` other than some edge effects on the timing of when `\everypar` tokens get triggered.

`\hbox` stack in vertical direction in vmode, and in horizontal direction in hmode (hence the names of the modes) which accounts for the different output that you show.

Perhaps you are asking about why

```
 \vbox{\leavevmode%
    \hbox{aaa}%
    \hbox{bbb}%
  }%
```

is so wide? Having started a paragraph inside the vbox, at the end of the box the paragraph is broken in to lines of length `\hsize` which is `\textwidth` here, so this box is the full width of the page.

Comment: `\protected\def\leavevmode{\ifvmode\expandafter\indent\fi}` ;)

Comment: @JosephWright i know, but the question didn't ask what `\ifvmode\expandafter\indent\fi` does:-)

Comment: Yes, that question (why so wide) is better. I'll try to edit the post.

Comment: @Sigur it is essentially unrelated to `\leavevmode` you see the same with `\vbox{\hbox{a}}` which is the width of an `a` and `\vbox{a}` which is the width of the page.

Comment: Now it is clearer. I was thinking that `\leavevmode` would cancel the vertical mode, but it wouldn't (as far as I'm understanding the discussion). I'm reading about it.

Comment: @Sigur it starts a paragraph in just the same way that `a` does, it's just less visible than an `a`

Comment: @Sigur try all your examples with `\leavevmode`  replaced by `z` and then you will see more clearly

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for attention. Amazing results.