# First character of `align*` not in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I'm having a really strange problem with the `align*` environment from `amsmath` (it happens with `align`, `aligned`, `gather`, etc. as well). For some reason, the first character is not in math mode, but the rest are. The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \ifmmode t \else f \fi
  \ifmmode t \else f \fi & =
  \ifmmode t \else f \fi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Produces: [image]

This is obviously a simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do, but I'm wondering what causes this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From showed image follows, that all characters are in "math" mode.

Comment: That conditional at the start might be the issue. Try with `\leavevmode\ifmmode ...`.

Comment: @Zarko Yeah, the characters themselves are, but the \ifmmode clearly says that its not, hence why I was confused.

Comment: @Werner That works! Thanks. What does \leavevmode do? Also do you want to make that an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @KevinFisher See [tex core - What does \leavevmode do? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522727/what-does-leavevmode-do) and the linked questions from that one — although to digest that answer you might want to read on horizontal and vertical mode (TeXbook page ??? or TeX by topic page 72.)

Comment: Probably same issue as [math mode - Correct usage of \ifmmode - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82653/correct-usage-of-ifmmode)  or  [math mode - \ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment) .

Comment: @user202729 You're totally right, I'm not sure how I missed those. Should this be marked as duplicate?

Comment: Okay, looks good. (the answer in the first one looks better, although funnily the (question, answer) pair have the exact same number of votes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment)